# Is there a way to get number of messages in Kafka topic

Tags: librdkafka, cppkafka

Is there a way to get number of unprocessed messages in Kafka topic using `cppkafka` or `librdkafka`? I guess it has something to do with offsets, but I'm unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md,
it is `consume.callback.max.messages`.
GitHub discussion: https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/issues/248